# Implicit conversion en C# generic classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have an application that is structured as an service layer wich uses a repository layer for persistence.
I'm trying to create a generic controller class to reuse shared behavior but I'm having trouble trying to set the generic parameters. The following code:

```
public class BusinessEntity
{ }

public class Person : BusinessEntity
{ }

public interface IRepository<T> where T : BusinessEntity
{ }

public interface IService<T, R>
    where T : BusinessEntity
    where R : IRepository<T>
{ }

public partial interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{ }

public interface IPersonService : IService<Person, IPersonRepository>
{ }

public abstract class BaseController<X, Y>
    where X : BusinessEntity
    where Y : IService<X, IRepository<X>>
{ }

public class PersonController : BaseController<Person, IPersonService>
{ }
```

fails at compilation with

The type `ConsoleApplication.IPersonService` cannot be used as type parameter `Y` in the generic type or method `ConsoleApplication.BaseController<X,Y>`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `ConsoleApplication.IPersonService` to `ConsoleApplication.IService<ConsoleApplication.Person,ConsoleApplication.IRepository<ConsoleApplication.Person>>`

this works

```
public interface IPersonService : IService<Person, IRepository<Person>>
```

but I lose the custom repository

There is a way to make the compiler realize `IPersonRepository` is an `IRepository<Person>`?

Comment: Right this is because `IRepository<X> where X:Person` is not the same as `IRepository<Person>` by default, no variance for such generic types by default. Which version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: If I had the ability, I'd award you a "broke the compiler" badge. From the whole 5 minutes I spent trying to make it work, my gut conclusion is that the compiler isn't smart enough to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I'm using .Net 4. I haven't thought of variance, I think it deserves a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class BusinessEntity
{ }

public class Person : BusinessEntity
{ }

public interface IRepository<T> where T : BusinessEntity
{ }

public interface IService<T, R>
    where T : BusinessEntity
    where R : IRepository<T>
{ }

public partial interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{ }

public interface IPersonService : IService<Person, IPersonRepository>
{ }

public abstract class BaseController<X, Y, Z>
    where X : BusinessEntity
    where Y : IService<X, Z>
    where Z : IRepository<X>
{ }

public class PersonController : BaseController<Person, IPersonService, IPersonRepository>
{ }
```

To address your comment:

> IPersonService can extend the base service class to add custom facilities, like FindPersonsUnderAge(). For this it requires a custom repository. Actually LINQ avoids a lot of custom repository code, but sometimes they are required.

Couldn't IPersonService do that without requiring the repository type to be a type parameter?  For example:

```
public interface IService<T> where T : BusinessEntity { } 

public interface IPersonService : IService<Person>
{
    IEnumerable<Person> FindPersonsByAge(double minAge, double maxAge);
}

public class Service<T, R> : IService<T>
    where T : BusinessEntity 
    where R : IRepository<T> 
{ }

public class PersonService : Service<Person, IPersonRepository>, IPersonService
{ }
```

Comment: I don't completely like the fact that the UI developer has to know about the repositories but it's an acceptable compromise.

Comment: @JamesGordon In that case, I'd shoot for `interface IPersonService : IService<Person>`, so the service's consumer doesn't need to know anything about how the service persists its data -- not even that it relies on an `IRepository<>`.  What methods of the PersonService require a type parameter for the person repository?

Comment: IPersonService can extend the base service class to add custom facilities, like FindPersonsUnderAge(). For this it requires a custom repository. Actually LINQ avoids a lot of custom repository code, but sometimes they are required.

Comment: @JamesGordon my question boils down to "where does `IService<T, R>` use its `R` type parameter?  Can't it just be `IService<T>`?  See the edited response for a sketch.

Comment: With the code i get it now. Yes, it's a cleaner solution. I mark your answer as the accepted one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sll for pointing me in the right direction

```
public interface IService<T, out R>
    where T : BusinessEntity
    where R : IRepository<T>
{ }
```

does the trick