# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'X' to 'Z<X, Y>'

Tags: .net, generics

So I am fully aware that there are many questions on this issue, the one coming the closest to mine being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608073/implicit-conversion-en-c-sharp-generic-classes).  However, I can't seem to correlate mine with that one despite the similarites, though my example is a bit more complex.

The below code can be copy-pasta'd into your own test app:

```
//Base class for all application entities
public abstract class AppEntity { }

public abstract class DocumentBase : AppEntity
{
    //some base class properties here
}

public abstract class DocumentTypeBase : AppEntity { }

public abstract class EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType> : DocumentBase
where TEntity : AppEntity
where TDocumentType : DocumentTypeBase
{
    public TEntity Parent { get; set; }
    public TDocumentType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : AppEntity { }

public class CustomerDocument : EntityDocumentBase<Customer, CustomerDocumentType> { }

public class CustomerDocumentType : DocumentTypeBase { }

//This is the base MVC controller
public class BaseController<T> where T : AppEntity, new() { }

//This controller derives from BaseController to consolidate all document management
public abstract class DocumentController<TEntity, TDocumentType> : BaseController<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType>, new()
    where TDocumentType : DocumentTypeBase
{ }

//This is the class definition that presents the issue
public class CustomerDocumentController : DocumentController<CustomerDocument, CustomerDocumentType>
{

}
```

What I don't understand is how it can't relate `CustomerDocument` to `EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType>` when `CustomerDocument` inherits from `EntityDocumentBase<Customer, CustomerDocumentType>`.

**Edit**

I love it when I muddy up SE with a question that's wrong to begin with.  After Phate01's answer pointed out my coding error, I was able to figure out the rest.

For anyone else having this issue, what you end up having to do is tell the base class how to reconstruct the generic type even though it may seem like it should be able to figure it out on its own.

```
//This controller derives from BaseController to consolidate all document management
public abstract class DocumentController<TEntityDocument, TEntity, TDocumentType> : BaseController<TEntityDocument>
    where TEntityDocument : EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType>, new()
    where TEntity : AppEntity
    where TDocumentType : DocumentTypeBase
{ }

//This is the class definition that presents the issue
public class CustomerDocumentController : DocumentController<CustomerDocument, Customer, CustomerDocumentType>
{

}
```

Comment: T<A> is a completely different class then T<B>. They have different class code and might have different behaviour.

Comment: Be careful what you asked for. You want TEntity to inherit from `EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType>`. That means that `CustomerDocument` should inherit EntityDocumentBase< **CustomerDocument** ,_>. That's not its signature though. This kind of confusion is just one reason why this way of specifying generic base types is frowned upon. It appeared briefly around the time generics were introduced as a way to decorate base types but fell out of use quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class DocumentController<TEntity, TDocumentType> : BaseController<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType>, new()
    where TDocumentType : DocumentTypeBase
{ }
```

Here you pass `CustomerDocument` as `TEntity`, and you say that `TEntity : EntityDocumentBase<TEntity, TDocumentType>, new()`

But `CustomerDocument` is of type `EntityDocumentBase<Customer, CustomerDocumentType>` while it's expecting a type of `EntityDocumentBase<CustomerDocument, CustomerDocumentType>`

Comment: I was swimming in generic parameters up to my eyes.  Lack of sleep caused me to near drown in them, so thanks for pointing out that error.  See update in question

Comment: You're welcome! Lack of sleep always brings to issues like this. I also did the changes you made but I wasn't sure of how you wanted to handle the problem